# Select form doesn't send POST

Tags: php, html

This would be a part of a search menu, but I can't get the POST from it. I searched for it, but cant make it work.

*Notice: Undefined index: Make in C:\xampp\htdocs\carsale\carsale_dropdown.php on line 3*

```html
<form name="mainForm" action="carsale_dropdown.php" method="POST">
      <select class="form-control" name="Make" >
        <option value="Nissan">Nissan</option>
        <option value="Toyota">Toyota</option>
      </select>
</form>
```

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['search'])){
  $selectedMake = $_POST['Make'];                
  $sql="SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE make=selectedMake";

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to send something via `$_POST` or `$_GET` you need to submit it. Therefore you need something like

```
<form name="mainForm" action="carsale_dropdown.php" method="POST">
<select class="form-control" name="Make" >
<option value="Nissan">Nissan</option>
<option value="Toyota">Toyota</option>
</select>
<button type="submit">Click</button>
</form>
```

Every form has to be submited.

Comment: You're right. Actually I have a submit button, but now I see what is my problem. I made two separated froms and put the button in the second, when I only have to have one form. Thanks!